# Problemas Instalando laravlel 6 con laravel Installer

Tags: laravel, windows, curl, redes, firewall

descargué laravel installer con composer de esta forma:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>composer global require laravel/installer
Changed current directory to C:/Users/jofre/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Using version ^3.0 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Pero cuando quiero instalar laravel con
`laravel new my-test-app` por ejemplo, me da el siguiente error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>Laravel new my-test-app
Crafting application...

In CurlFactory.php line 200:

  cURL error 28: Failed to connect to 190.195.101.53 port 1080: Timed out (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl
  -errors.html)


new [--dev] [--auth] [-f|--force] [--] [<name>]
```

Alguna cosa que esté haciendo mal?

Comment: Tienes problemas de conexión. Verifica firewalls, proxies, etc. Chequea la configuración de tu sistema operativo, del punto de acceso, de tu proveedor, etc. O conéctate a internet desde otro punto de acceso.

Comment: hola en que sentido, puedo conectarme a internet, incluso tengo conexion por cable, no wifi. Que me sugieres. Pasos a seguir? Lo raro es que puedo descargar por ejemplo usando el siguiente comando composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "6.*",

Comment: Prueba desactivando el firewall de windows (o en su defecto, windows defender). En ocasiones, este bloquea algunos puertos.

Comment: hola Edgar desistale el firewal y windows defender pero tengo el mismo error, qué más puedo probar?